# Derivative calculation $\frac{d}{dz}\cos(yz)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Perhaps the question that I am about to write may seem trivial, but I just started to study the course of Complex Analysis. The question is the following.

I have to calculate the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dz}\cos(xz)$$
with $z\in \mathbb C$ and $x\in \mathbb R$. If I apply the same rules of the derivatives on $\mathbb R$, I should get
$$-x \sin (x z)$$
My doubt is: can I use the same derivation rules known on $\mathbb R$? And then: is correct my result?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same rules for taking derivatives and yes, your result is correct.

Comment: @msteve Thanks!

Comment: But, you should prove that you can use the same rules. Take the proofs of the rules in the real setting, and see that the proofs all work (with occasionally minor modifications, maybe) too for the complex derivative.

Comment: "can I use the same derivation rules known on R ?": not yet heard of holomorphic functions and the Cauchy-Riemann condition ?? This is the very heart of complex analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, thats true, because you are able to differentiate (inside the convergence-disc) any power-series "term by term" i.e.

$$f'(z)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k \right)^{'}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ka_kz^{k-1} \right) $$